# Is it possible to add a local package with a setup.py as a dependency in the main package's setup.py file?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I have the following directory structure with a local submodule (that does not exist on git)

```
root
|
|___Dependency
|   |__________setup.py
|
|___MainPackage
    |___________setup.py
```

I don't want to add the source code of the dependency inside the MainPackage since it doesn't really belong there, is it possible to point the setup.py file of the main package to the local dependency?

Right now my solution is to run a post-installation script that installs the dependency using pip, however this means if I run the `setup.py test` commmand, I will have to manually install the dependency otherwise the tests will fail.